# bitmap character customization like pou game

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing, sprite

im new to android , of course Ive worked with c# and java script in unity , but for some reasons im going to make my new app in android....
one of my problem is that the base structure in unity is different with android
in unity  i could make a parent with a sprite renderer and put childs for it and each child got its own position and its own renderer , so i could change the renderer sprites at anytime for character customization .., now in android i see just view controllers like listvie ,textview and etc....so would anyone tell me please that how can i correctly position my six bitmaps for building my character and then change the bitmaps for different parts like eyes ,glasses...

Comment: no one answers ,this is an important issue for many of android developers....:( –

Comment: still no reply...and im wondering why....

Comment: this link maybe help you : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59757/what-kind-of-technique-is-used-in-android-game-rendering-like-pou?newreg=bb3e56538f324c45a1f935d3add698b7